# how to make my async function a promise in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in AngularJS and i have a service in which the post method is:

```
var xhrService = {
  post: function(url, data) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.send(data);
    return xhr;
}}
```

I want to be able to use this service just like the built-in (angular) [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service with a success & error methods.
It would be very good if no other library is used.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `$http` service?

Comment: He doesn't have to, he can do it himself (see my answer below). But I agree using `$http` is standard and recommended. But if he wants for whatever reason, he can live without it.

Comment: I'm using xhr to upload files ... is there a way to do that with `$http` service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need at least `$q` service to create `deferred`, you return `deferred.promise` from the function. Then you either resolve or reject it based on the result.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url);

req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      deferred.resolve(req.response);
    }
    else {
      deferred.reject(req.statusText);
    }
}

req.onerror = function() {
  deferred.reject('error');
};

req.send();

return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Looks good as far as I can tell, except that you're not `send()`ing the XHR?

Comment: thanks, although i wanted to use `success` & `error` not `then`

Comment: `success` and `error` methods are specific for `$http` service which extends the standard promise API. There is no difference in the code execution if you use `then` or `success` and `error`